# Build errors when importing an existing project to Android Studio from GitHub

Tags: java, android, obd-ii

I am new to Android Studio so I am trying to edit an existing project to understand the environment.
My idea was to make an app to control an OBD device (for cars), I've found a lot of projects but I can't import them without receiving errors and errors.

So, currently, I'm trying with https://github.com/fr3ts0n/AndrOBD
Simply I've downloaded all the source and opened them with Android Studio

As soon as I try to launch the emulator it says: "Build failed" with 1 error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':androbd:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project: plugin.
     Required by:
         project: android
      > No matching configuration of project :plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

I can't understand how to make it works, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the plugin too, since it's in a different repo.

With git

```
git clone https://github.com/fr3ts0n/AndrOBD.git --recurse-submodules
```